# Install error using pip for the beir package

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, nlp, information-retrieval

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pytrec-eval
  Building wheel for pytrec-eval (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [259 lines of output]
      Fetching trec_eval from https://github.com/usnistgov/trec_eval/archive/v9.0.8.tar.gz.
      /home/ed19b065/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:472: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.
      
              By 2024-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
     
      In file included from /usr/include/string.h:535,
                       from /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/sysfunc.h:23,
                       from /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:9:
      In function ‘strncpy’,
          inlined from ‘get_long_cutoffs’ at /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:276:12,
          inlined from ‘te_init_meas_a_float_cut_long’ at /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:97:16:
      /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:95:10: warning: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ specified bound depends on the length of the source argument [-Wstringop-truncation]
         95 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len,
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         96 |                                   __glibc_objsize (__dest));
            |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c: In function ‘te_init_meas_a_float_cut_long’:
      /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:278:21: note: length computed here
        278 |                     strlen(param_string)+1);
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/string.h:535,
                       from /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/sysfunc.h:23,
                       from /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:9:
      In function ‘strncpy’,
          inlined from ‘get_float_cutoffs’ at /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:333:12,
          inlined from ‘te_init_meas_a_float_cut_float’ at /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:140:16:
      /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:95:10: warning: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ specified bound depends on the length of the source argument [-Wstringop-truncation]
         95 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len,
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         96 |                                   __glibc_objsize (__dest));
            |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c: In function ‘te_init_meas_a_float_cut_float’:
      /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:335:21: note: length computed here
        335 |                     strlen(param_string)+1);
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/string.h:535,
                       from /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/sysfunc.h:23,
                       from /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:9:
      In function ‘strncpy’,
          inlined from ‘get_float_params’ at /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:386:12,
          inlined from ‘te_init_meas_s_float_p_float’ at /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:186:16:
      /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:95:10: warning: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ specified bound depends on the length of the source argument [-Wstringop-truncation]
         95 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len,
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         96 |                                   __glibc_objsize (__dest));
            |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c: In function ‘te_init_meas_s_float_p_float’:
      /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:388:21: note: length computed here
        388 |                     strlen(param_string)+1);
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/string.h:535,
                       from /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/sysfunc.h:23,
                       from /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:9:
      In function ‘strncpy’,
          inlined from ‘get_param_pairs’ at /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:445:12,
          inlined from ‘te_init_meas_s_float_p_pair’ at /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:225:16:
      /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:95:10: warning: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ specified bound depends on the length of the source argument [-Wstringop-truncation]
         95 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len,
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         96 |                                   __glibc_objsize (__dest));
            |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c: In function ‘te_init_meas_s_float_p_pair’:
      /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_init.c:447:21: note: length computed here
        447 |                     strlen(param_string)+1);
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DVERSIONID=\"pytrec_eval\" -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DP_NEEDS_GNU_CXX_NAMESPACE=1 -UNDEBUG -I/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8 -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_print_final.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_print_final.o -g -Wall -O3
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DVERSIONID=\"pytrec_eval\" -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DP_NEEDS_GNU_CXX_NAMESPACE=1 -UNDEBUG -I/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8 -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_print_single.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/meas_print_single.o -g -Wall -O3
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DVERSIONID=\"pytrec_eval\" -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DP_NEEDS_GNU_CXX_NAMESPACE=1 -UNDEBUG -I/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8 -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/measures.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/measures.o -g -Wall -O3
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DVERSIONID=\"pytrec_eval\" -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DP_NEEDS_GNU_CXX_NAMESPACE=1 -UNDEBUG -I/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8 -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c /tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/utility_pool.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8/utility_pool.o -g -Wall -O3
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DVERSIONID=\"pytrec_eval\" -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DP_NEEDS_GNU_CXX_NAMESPACE=1 -UNDEBUG -I/tmp/tmp4xtauf21/trec_eval-9.0.8 -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/pytrec_eval.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/src/pytrec_eval.o -g -Wall -O3
      src/pytrec_eval.cpp:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
          1 | #include <Python.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytrec-eval
  Running setup.py clean for pytrec-eval
Failed to build pytrec-eval
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pytrec-eval, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I get this error while installing the beir package. I have tried to resolve it by installing directly from [source](https://github.com/cvangysel/pytrec_eval). I have also tried to manually add the "Python.h" file to my source folder and none them seem to work.
All my installations are being done using `pip install beir` or `pip install pytrec-eval` and for the manual one `CPPFLAGS="-I/path/to/Python.h" pip install pytrec-eval`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention im using Ubuntu 22.04.3 @ewokx

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Ubuntu; but do you have python-devel installed? (or whatever the Ubuntu equivalent is).  Also,  ```-I``` points to a directory, not a filename (well..afaik).

Comment: thanks but i managed to solve it found the header file online @ewokx

Answer (score 1):

Found the [File](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r32b2/Include/Python.h) and added it to anaconda3/include/python3.10 and ran `CPPFLAGS="-I/anaconda3/include/python3.10/" pip install pytrec-eval`